# What is the number of free parameters for the k-means algorithm?

Tags: k-means

When

```
p = the number of data points to cluster
k = the number of clusters
n = the number of dimensions of each data point
```

what is the number of free parameters for the k-means algorithm?

Each centroid has `n` elements, which means for all centroids we have `n*k` free parameters. What else?

Comment: What are "free parameters"?

Comment: Those are the number of model parameters to be estimated.

Answer (score 1):

The initial step of k-means is to randomly select 'k' cluster centroids. Normally they are selected from the data points itself to ensure fast convergence.

This contributes n*k parameters as you mentioned.

We also have to assign labels to each of the 'p' data points based on a distance measure to the cluster centroids.

This requires 'p' additional variables.

Comment: I don't think I'd call the cluster assignments free parameters, because they're completely determined by the centroid locations and the distance metric. They're more like outputs.

Comment: Yes, actually that was the part I was confused. Once we know the centroids, we can just get the cluster assignments, so this means cluster assignments are not "free" parameters. But this is true for vice versa; once we know the cluster assignments, we can easily get the cluster centroids; then the cluster assignments are not "free" any more. That's confusing...

Comment: Cluster assignments are necessary to update the centroid. Even though they are not free parameters, they are necessary.